# Infinite scroll with jquery .load() function

Tags: jquery, scroll, load, infinite

In a Wordpress blog page I'm trying to load content with jquery .load() function:

```
<div id="s1"> 1 </div>
<div id="s2"> 2 </div>
<div id="s3"> 3 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#s1").load("/2013 article.item-list");
$("#s2").load("/2013/page/2/ article.item-list");
$("#s3").load("/2013/page/3/ article.item-list");
</script>
```

Until here, everything works fine.
But I want the content from `<div id="s2">` to load when I scroll down, like a lazy load, and so on for every next `<div>`. Like on mashable.com

I tried with jscroll and Infinite Scroll jQuery Plugin, but I can't figure out how to make this work.

Please someone to give me a hint!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the scroll event handler and then use scrollTop() and innerHeight() to figure out if your at the end of the div or not. When you are call another load.

```
$('#s1').on('scroll', function(){

     if($(this).scrollTop()+ $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this).scrollHeight)
                  $("#s2").load("/2013/page/2/ article.item-list");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From krosullivan ideea, I made this code and works fine (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w7X9N/272/).

But when I test this on my website, its not working. I have to set `height:500px;` and `overflow:auto;` style properties to `<div="lazy">` to make it work (like in my demo).

Any ideas ?

```
<div id="lazy">
<div id="s1">1</div>
<div id="s2">2</div>
<div id="s3">3</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(
function($) {
    $("#s1").load("/2013/ article.item-list");
    $('#lazy').bind('scroll', function()
    {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
        {
            $("#s2").load("/2013/page/2/ article.item-list");
            $('#lazy').bind('scroll', function()
            {
                if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
                {
                    $("#s3").load("/2013/page/3/ article.item-list");   
                }                                 
            })
        }                                 
    })
});
</script>`
```